# Java Char increment

Tags: java, char, post-increment

I was executing the following code

```
class First
{

 public static void main(String arg[])
        {
            char x= 'A';
            x = x++;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
}
```

Here the output is A. 
My question is why didn't x get incremented before printing.

Comment: What if your line `x = x++;` just said `x++;`?  What happens then?

Comment: It did. It didn't get incremented before *assigning*, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the post-increment operator incorrectly - you don't need to use assignment as well.  And in this case it undermines what you're trying to do.

For context, remember that the post-increment operator increases the value, *and returns the old value*.  That is, `x++` is roughly equivalent to:

```
int x_initial = x;
x = x + 1;
return x_initial;
```

Hopefully now you can see why your code is failing to change `x`.  If you expand it, it looks like:

```
char x= 'A';
char y;
{
    y = x;
    x = x + 1;
}
x = y;
System.out.println(x);
```

and the net effect of the assignment, is to set `x` back to what it was originally.

---

To fix - you can simply call `x++`.  Or, if you want to make it clear there's some sort of assignment happening, `x += 1` or even just `x = x + 1` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
class First
{

 public static void main(String arg[])
        {
            char x= 'A';
            x = x++;   // it is post increment as ++ sign is after x
            System.out.println(x);
        }
}
```

Post Increment(x++) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.

Pre Increment (++x) : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.